# How to fix 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: c#, excel, data-driven-tests

I am trying to read data from multiple sheets in a single excel file and in the process I have been having one issue or the other. The current problem i have now is on 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' which I get while performing a test.

I have tried using OLEDB connection but to no avail. I'm still new in coding and would appreciate any help.

// singleton object of 
    public class ExcelDataContext
    {
        // creating an object of ExcelDataContext
        private static readonly ExcelDataContext Instance = new ExcelDataContext();

```
    // no instantiated available
    private static DataTable GetExcelDataContext(string filename)
    {
        FileStream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
            {
                UseHeaderRow = true
            }
        });


        foreach (DataTable sheet in result.Tables)
        {
            DataTableCollection tableCollection = result.Tables;
            if (sheet.Equals(tableCollection["loginData"]))
            {
                DataTable loginDataTable = GetInstance().Sheets["loginData"];
                return loginDataTable;

            }
            if (sheet.Equals(tableCollection["homeData"]))
            {
                DataTable homeDataTable = GetInstance().Sheets["homeData"];

                return homeDataTable;
            }
            excelReader.Close();
        }
        return new DataTable();
    }

    // accessing to ExcelDataContext singleton
    public static ExcelDataContext GetInstance()
    {
        return Instance;
    }

    // the dataset of Excel
    public DataTableCollection Sheets => null;


    public class DataCollection
    {
        public int RowNumber { get; set; }
        public string ColName { get; set; }
        public string ColValue { get; set; }
    }

    static readonly List<DataCollection> DataCollections = new List<DataCollection>();

    public static void PopulateInCollection(string filename)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = GetExcelDataContext(filename);
        for (int row = 1; row <= dataTable.Rows.Count; row++) //row =1 because we are  not using header name
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < dataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                DataCollection collection = new DataCollection()
                {
                    RowNumber = row,
                    ColName = dataTable.Columns[col].ColumnName, //return column name
                    ColValue = dataTable.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                };
                DataCollections.Add(collection);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
    {
        try
        {
            string data =
            (from colData in DataCollections
                where colData.ColName == columnName && colData.RowNumber == rowNumber
                select colData.ColValue).SingleOrDefault();

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

i am expecting to be able to get the data from each excel sheet.

Comment: debug and check on what line the exception is thrown

Comment: this error means u r trying to access something which is not existed (null) , something should be there but it's not , for example in this line

 foreach (DataTable sheet in result.Tables)

if results.Tables is not there , a similar exception will be thrown
you need to know which which line is throwing this exception first , then you can check why it's null or how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: There is no instantiated object. Try to find which of the class isn't instatiated by debugging.

Comment: I would suggest adding links to preexisting answered questions (if they have been properly answered and are useful) instead answering duplicated questions.